# Why do most Javascript libraries append the not operator to their IIFEs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've noticed that most/very close to all Javascript libraries (jQuery, require, moment and loads more) append their IIFE with the `not` operator (`!`). Could someone explain why this is done, and the advantages of using the not operator with IIFEs?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

```js
//jquery
! function(e, t) {
  //requirejs
  var requirejs, require, define;
  ! function
  //moment
  ! function(e, t) {
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Oh sorry, editing question now.

Comment: Dupe answers it; IMO it's a pointless way of writing it, and just obfuscates intent.